# Protege fuzzyOWL2 plugin fuzzy query

Tags: sparql, ontology, protege, fuzzy-logic, swrl

I'm learning fuzzy ontology . There are several different ways like F-swrl , [owl2 fuzzy plugin](http://www.umbertostraccia.it/cs/software/FuzzyOWL), fsparql. But it seems owl2 fuzzy plugin to be the most famous plugin for fuzzifying.

[Some researchers](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5383759/) have only used SWRL and [others](http://www.ccsenet.org/journal/index.php/cis/article/view/61140/33184) used a combination of SWRL and fuzzyowl2 plugin to implement  fuzzy ontology.

I've downloaded [fuzzyWine.owl](http://www.umbertostraccia.it/cs/software/FuzzyOWL/ontologies/FuzzyWine.1.0.owl), which includes a number of classes, data/object properties and datatypes. But there's no example for fuzzy queries.

I do not know if the query should be run in fuzzy reasoner tab or by SWRL rules. I need to have a simple example of fuzzy query using this ontology to understand the fuzzy ontology better.

Comment: Using the SWRL rules tab doesn't do anything besides adding SWRL rules to the ontology which are then be used by the OWL reasoner (if they support SWRL indeed). Fuzzy queries have to be executed in the corresponding FuzzyOWL tab.

Comment: @AKSW can you provide me a simple fuzzy query for fuzzyWine.owl to be executed  in fuzzyOWL tab?

Comment: While it wouldn't consider the fuzzy annotations and should return 1.0, you should start with `(concept-subsumes? Wine SparklingWine)`. The syntax for queries is FuzzyDL, documentation is [here](http://www.umbertostraccia.it/cs/software/fuzzyDL/fuzzyDL.html) and in *query expression* section of [this link](http://www.umbertostraccia.it/cs/software/fuzzyDL/syntax.html)

Comment: @AKSW running this query  causes the following error:`Uncaught Exception in thread AWT-EventQueue-0
fuzzydl.parser.TokenMgrError: Lexical error at line 863, column 18.  Encountered: "?" (63), after : ""
        at fuzzydl.parser.ParserTokenManager.getNextToken(ParserTokenManager.java:2203)` 
     I'm running win10 protege 4.3 gurobi.6.5(license is not installed!)

Answer (score 0):

The Plugin "OWL2 Fuzzy" was documented with examples in a published paper by its authors.

Fernando Bobillo, Umberto Straccia. Fuzzy ontology representation using OWL 2. International Journal of Approximate Reasoning archive, Volume 52 Issue 7, Pages 1073-1094, October, 2011.

Hope you success,

With best Wishes

Comment: Thanks @mohammad . I've read that [paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0888613X11000855) , but    i am looking for a step by step guide concerned on fuzzy query.